# Indicate end of a group

Tags: apiblueprint

In the groups example https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/master/examples/04.%20Grouping%20Resources.md it says that the end of a groups is indicated by the start of another group. Is there a way to indicate the end of a group without having to start another group? E.g. instead of

```
# Group Messages
## My Message [/message]
### Update a Message [PUT]
### Delete a Message [DELETE]
# Group Users
...
```

I'd like to do

```
# Group Messages
## My Message [/message]
### Update a Message [PUT]
### Delete a Message [DELETE]
# Users 
...
```

Where `Users` doesn't have to be a group. However, right now it seems in the second e.g., `Users` would still be under the previous group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, that is not supported. You have to start a new group as in your example.